# Map specific AWS ECS tasks to either FARGATE or FARGATE_SPOT capacity providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an AWS ECS cluster with two types of tasks. I want to be able to schedule one type on FARGATE provider and another on FARGATE_SPOT.

Official tutorial mentions provider strategies, which use weights to distribute tasks, however it is not clear how to map tasks by type.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[This workshop](https://ecsworkshop.com) and [this page specifically](https://ecsworkshop.com/capacity_providers/fargate/) shows how to set it up.

The core of it is:

```
aws ecs put-cluster-capacity-providers \
--cluster container-demo \
--capacity-providers FARGATE FARGATE_SPOT \
--default-capacity-provider-strategy \
capacityProvider=FARGATE,weight=1,base=1 \
capacityProvider=FARGATE_SPOT,weight=4
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I've seen this part, but the question is a bit different: "Official tutorial mentions provider strategies, which use weights to distribute tasks, however it is not clear **how to map tasks by type.**"

Comment: A `task` is launched off of a `task definition` and when you launch a service you can pick a `capacity provider strategy` which basically defines the ratio of tasks coming off each single capacity provider. The tasks are exactly the same (same task def) but how they are launched change (fargate, fargate spot, ec2). There is a default capacity provider strategy at the cluster level (above) but you can create custom strategies per service. In this context, what do you mean by ***how to map tasks by type***?  Also, what is the link to the "official tutorial" you are alluding too? Thanks.

Comment: Or better, what would you like to achieve?

Comment: I have two task definitions: scheduler and worker. I want to run scheduler on FARGATE and worker on FARGATE_SPOT in the same cluster

Comment: In which case you would need to create two ECS services. Say `worker` and `scheduler` each pointing to their task def. The `worker` service will have a custom capacity provider strategy that would only have `FARGATE_SPOT` as the capacity provider and the `scheduler` service will have a custom capacity provider strategy that would only have `FARGATE` as the capacity provider.  Note that `FARGATE` and `FARGATE_SPOT` are existing managed out of the box capacity providers so you don't need to create them upfront

Comment: Doing this in the UI is fairly straightforward and guided, if you use the AWS CLI you need to use the [create-service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/create-service.html) command and configure properly the `--capacity-provider-strategy` flag.

Comment: The problem I see here is that if I start using ECS services I essentially delegate scheduling logic to ECS while I want my scheduler to do the job. Fargate does not allow DAEMON schedulingStrategy, which means I have to modify my scheduler to explicitly tell ECS how many workers I need. Any way to bypass this?

Comment: I continue to be slightly confused by this. `DAEMONs` are constructs that you can use when there are nodes involved. Fargate allows you to run containerized workloads without nodes. You seem to be saying that the number of `workers` need to be a function of the number of nodes you have? That's weird because usually it's the other way around (e.g. you schedule workloads and infrastructure reacts to provision the nodes required - and Fargate removes that need altogether).

Comment: The canonical way you would do this is by telling the ECS service `min`-`max`-`desired` number of `workers` you need (and `schedulers`). Then you can control the exact number of tasks by tweaking the `desired` parameter. You can do that manually (with external logic you own) OR you can leverage ECS built-in autoscaling mechanism by providing scaling rules (based on resource utilization, queue depths etc)

Comment: The reason I mentioned DAEMON is because I don't want to delegate scheduling logic to Service (so disregard this, I may have misused this term here since I assumed DAEMON schedulingStrategy does not required desired number of tasks as a parameter).

Comment: The problem with the cannonical way, is that I already have a scheduling logic which only requires interface to launch tasks, not setting min/max/desired to another Service abstraction (my custom scheduler keeps the service/cluster state internally). Integrating Amazon's Service will require re-designing this logic, adding more complexity I'm trying to avoid. Does this make sense?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider/issues/47 last comment for more context

Comment: Oh... I see. I put a comment on the GH issue as well but the long story short is that you can indeed launch a one-off task(s) using the run-task API. Basically, instead of using the ECS service scheduler, it allows an external scheduler to launch/stop tasks. You can launch both Fargate and FARGATE_SPOT standalone Fargate tasks using the `--launch-type` flag for FARGATE and the `--capacity-provider-strategy` for FARGATE_SPOT. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) the doc for the details.